# How to marshall void* with platform invoke

Tags: c#

I need to call a function from a C api contained in a dll.  Function prototype looks as follows....

```
int func( char* name, void* value );
```

where the contents of the pointer value can refer to any type dependent on the passed name.  I an unsure how to set up the Dll inport to correctly marshall this void *.   Ihave been experimenting with IntPtr which seems to work whe the value is an int but I cannot retrieve values correctly for floats etc.

I am trying to import the function like this...

```
[DllImport("dllname.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern int func( string name, ref IntPtr value );
```

pls note that value is an output.  A pointer to a value of any type, i.e. the address in a global region of memory of a value of a known type (known to the caller).  In a c prog the caller would then be expected to cast this void * to the desired type and dereference to get the actual value stored there.   The answers given so far seem to be based around an assumption that the function will write the result to pointer location passed in.  My fault as I haven't been too specific.  Sorry.  C# is not my bag, and I don't even know if IntPtr is the way to go here...

Answer (score 11):

The best way to tackle this is to provide overloads of the function so everything is squeaky clean on the C# side.  Like this:

```
[DllImport("dllname.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern int func(string name, out int value);
[DllImport("dllname.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern int func(string name, out float value);
// etc, one each for each type
```

Comment: agreed, provided the C code can be modified this is the best solution.

Comment: @Steve - no modification of the C code is necessary.  It just sees the pointer that the pinvoke marshaller passes.

Comment: then this is the best solution and the +1 is even more well-deserved

Answer (score 2):

You do not need the `ref` - `IntPtr` is the way to pass `void*` to native code.

```
[DllImport("dllname.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern int func( string name, IntPtr value );
```

EDIT:
The C code can use the input to write to the required memory.  The problem you face is for the managed code to know how much memory to allocate for each possible return value type. Then an appropriate sized block can be allocated using `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` or `Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem`, freed (according to which allocation method you use) use via `FreeHGlobal` or `FreeCoTaskMem`, once managed code is done with the output value.

See answer from @Alex Farber for an example.

Comment: I should have been more specific sorry.  The IntPtr value is an output.  In the case of this function it will be a pointer to a value which can be of any type.  The caller is expected to know the type they are trying to retrieve.

Comment: @matt - check out @Hans's answer and comments - this is your best bet.

Comment: Still not sure I have been specific enough...  The function will return a pointer to a value stored in a global region of memory which can then be dereferenced by type to get the actual value stored at that location...

Comment: @matt - your C code cannot possibly return a pointer via a parameter of `void*`.  That's an input parameter.  Did you mean `void**` ? Perhaps this is why you are having problems solving this issue.

Comment: @steve - its a pointer which is set to point to a value within a memory region.

Answer (score 2):

```
[DllImport("dllname.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)] 
public static extern int func( string name, IntPtr value ); 

...

// n - number of bytes which is enough to keep any type used by function
IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(n);
func(name, ptr);

// Use Marshal.ReadByte, Marshal.ReadInt32 ... or Marshal.Copy
// to copy from ptr filled by func to managed variable. For example:
byte b = Marshal.ReadByte(ptr);

Marshal.FreeHGlobal(IntPtr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, it might be easier to use this approach.

Declaration:

```
[DllImport("dllname.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern int func([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string name, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AsAny)] object value);
```

Example usage to pass a value:

```
func("some string", (int)12);
func("some string", (double)12);
```

Example usage to pass a string:

```
func("some string", "test");
```

Example usage to pass a variable:

```
int value = 12;
func("some string", value);
```